# Chrome file upload bug: on change event won't be executed twice with the same file

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, file-upload, onchange

I am working on this html5 file uploader plugin but it has a bug on **Google Chrome** which I can't understand and fix it. It works fine on Firefox.

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kWX9s/)

The problem is that you **cannot** upload the same file **twice** from your desktop.

When you first click, select, and hit OK to upload a file from your desktop, it should alert a message, for instance '.button-1' - depends on which upload button you click.

Then if you try to upload **the same file** again, this line of code won't be executed anymore,

```
$(".upload-file",object_parent).change(function() {

             ...
             ...

             alert($cm.selector);

});
```

Any idea what goes wrong in this plugin?

```
(function($){

    // Attach this new method to jQuery
    $.fn.extend({ 

        // This is where you write your plugin's name
        upload_file_html5: function(options) {

            // Set the default values, use comma to separate the settings, example:
            var defaults = {
                objectSuperparent:    '.media'
            }

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
            var o = options;

            var $cm = this.click(function(e){

                // <a> button is the object in this case.
                var object = $(this);

                // Get other info from the element belong to this object group.
                var object_href = object.attr('href');
                var object_parent = object.parent();
                alert($cm.selector);

                // Trigger the click event on the element.
                // Due to security policies triggering click on the input type=file is not allowed/supported in some browsers and Opera is one of them.
                //$('input[type=file]').trigger('click'); // or:
                $(".upload-file",object_parent).click();

                return false;

            });

            // Trigger ajax post when ever the file is changed by the user.
            var $cm_2 = $(".upload-file").change(function(){

                // <input> is the object in this case.
                var object = $(this);

                var object_form = object.parent();
                var object_superparent = object.parents(o.objectSuperparent);
                var path_config = $($cm.selector,object_superparent).attr('href');
                var path_post = object_form.attr('action');

                alert($cm.selector);
                //alert(path_config);

                ....
                ....

            });

        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

It was working OK on Chrome but just failed recently, probably Chrome has updated a latest version to my machine and this update causes the bug?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. My Chrome has different behavior to Firefox, but I think Chrome is correct.

According to [W3C's document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#adef-onchange):

> onchange event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus

if you try to upload the same file, the value of file input does not change. Try to print it out:

```
$('.button-2').click(function(){
    console.log($(".list .upload-file").val())
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks. I should not use onchange event then? or any way can I do so that I can upload the same file? thanks :-)

Comment: see @fundon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11280864/2024242) below for a working solution

Comment: yep, was choosing the same file

Answer (score 50):

If you want to upload twice, clear file input value

```
$('input[type="file"]').val(null);
```

[jsfiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/cfddream/BF8Gc/)

Comment: I would remove the jsfiddle link, the "objectSuperparent" and all the code confuses a bit.

Comment: Thank you, was pulling my hair out over this!

Answer (score 2):

it might be that the input is being re-rendered. For whatever reason this may be, for me its irrelevant.
The $.on('change', callback) functionality is lost.

Try using .delegate function which I absolutely love!
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Ok so delegate is exactly the same, it just tells jquery if there is an element rendered on screen with a particular handle, attach a functionality to it.

So even if the element is re-rendered, it will still keep to function.

```
$(document).delegate('.file_upload_btn', 'change', function(){});
```

You may think this is a throw away function & say whats the difference but this has saved me a lot of time on projects.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be caused as the file doesn't change and the onchange function doesn't get triggered. This can be solved by cleaning up the value after every upload.

```html
<input type="file" onChange={handelChange}/>
```

```js
function handelChange(event){
//your logic here

//on finish
e.target.value="" // this works!



// e.taget.value=null doesn't work for some reason
}
```