# How to handle file uploads when a file with same name exists using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, pug, formidable

I am using `formidable` node module for uploading the file.
Here is my .jade code

```
  form#uploadForm(enctype='multipart/form-data', method='POST', action='/upload')
    input#uploadTestSheet(type='file', name='uploadTestSheet', accept='.csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel')
    button(type='submit') Submit
```

The files are getting uploaded but if a file already exists in the directory and then a user is trying to add a file with the same name then the new file is not getting uploaded.
Here is my Server

```
var fs = require('node-fs-extra');
           var formidable = require('formidable');

    app.use(bodyparser({defer: true}));
    app.post('/upload',function (req, res, next) {

        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

        form.uploadDir =__dirname +"/uploads";
        form.keepExtensions = true;     
        form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
              fs.rename(files.uploadTestSheet.path,__dirname +'/uploads'+files.uploadTestSheet.name, function(err) {
           if (err){
               res.render('ManualMode',{data:{id:req.user.id, hash:req.user.hash, nodePollInterval:req.user.nodePollInterval}});
               console.log("cannot upload: "+err);
           }  
           });
           res.render('index',{data:{id:req.user.id, hash:req.user.hash, nodePollInterval:req.user.nodePollInterval}});
       });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fs.rename` method follows linux conventions, so it should be overwriting the files in the directory. This leads me to think that maybe your problem is in the browser. Chrome for instance, [will refuse to upload files of the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155136/chrome-file-upload-bug-on-change-event-wont-be-executed-twice-with-the-same-fi) without first clearing the `value` property in the input field. In your case, assuming your uploading is asynchronous, this would do:

```
document.getElementById('uploadTestSheet').value = ''; // after each upload
```

If you have verified that this is not the issue, try deleting the potentially existent file before renaming it, something along the lines of:

```
...
var newFilename = __dirname + '/uploads' + files.uploadTestSheet.name
try {
  fs.unlinkSync(newFilename)
} catch (e) {
  if (e.code !== 'ENOENT')
    throw err; 
}

fs.rename(files.uploadTestSheet.path, newFilename, function(err) {
...
```

I hope that helps!