# file input change event is ignored when same filename is uploaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm my Vue.js app I'm using Vuetify's [v-file-input](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/file-inputs/) component. The uploaded file is bound to `formData.file` and I validate the uploaded file via the `rules` prop.

```html
<v-file-input
  :rules="fileValidationRules"
  v-model="formData.file"
/>
```

If I upload a file `/tmp/foo.txt` everything works as expected, However, if I change the content of this file and upload it again, `fileValidationRules` is not called.

Apparently the reason for is because [Chrome does not trigger the change event if the file name is the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9156783/2648). Is there some way I can workaround this to ensure that every file selected by the user is bound to `formData.file` and calls `fileValidationRules`?

Comment: Did you try clearing the input value of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of the input to null on each onclick event. This will reset the input's value and trigger the onchange event even if the same path is selected.

```
input.onclick = function () {
    this.value = null;
};

input.onchange = function () {
    alert(this.value);
};​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of the file input as null.

```html
<v-file-input
  :rules="fileValidationRules"
  v-model="formData.file"
  ref="file"
/>
```

```js
onClick() {
   this.$refs.file.value = null;
}
```